# What is the standard way of calling swap for arguments defined by template?

Tags: c++, stl

What is the standard way of calling swap() for arguments defined by template?

Obviously calling `std::swap()` is not correct, as it would not pick up the swap declared in the same namespace as the type.
It seems that inserting a `using namespace std;` is not correct as it leads to errors.
Should one insert a `using std::swap;`?

Comment: You should add an example code to your question.

Comment: The cited answer does not apply to my question! I did not ask how to implement a swap but how to call it.

Comment: @NathanOliver How does the linked dup answer the question? Vote to reopen.

Comment: The standard way is to define the custom swap() in the namespace of your special-needs type.  Then, for calling from within a template, use `using namespace std; swap(u, v);`  This shoudl then resolve to the swap() in the right namespace.  As described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable

Comment: @MichaëlRoy it is better to use `using std::swap;` in that case, rather than `using namespace std;`

Comment: No. `using std::swap(); swap(u, v);`  will make std::swap() rhe default and effectively hide swap functions from other namespaces.   `using namespace std; swap(u, v);` will _default_to std::swap if an overloaded swap is not found in the namespace of the type being swapped.  That's a big big difference.

Answer (score 1):

The standard requirement for ["swappable types"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable) is `swap(t, u)` where [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) from the `<utility>` header is a viable candidate.

This is satisfied by both `using namespace std;` and if a `using std::swap;`. The standard way given is the latter (https://wg21.link/swappable.requirements#6):

```cpp
#include <utility>

// Preconditions: std​::​forward<T>(t) is swappable with std​::​forward<U>(u).
template<class T, class U>
void value_swap(T&& t, U&& u) {
  using std::swap;
  swap(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u)); // OK, uses “swappable with'' conditions
                                                // for rvalues and lvalues
}

// Preconditions: lvalues of T are swappable.
template<class T>
void lv_swap(T& t1, T& t2) {
  using std::swap;
  swap(t1, t2);                                 // OK, uses swappable conditions for lvalues of type T
}
```

For swapping two lvalues of the same type, you can also use [`std::iter_swap(std::addressof(a), std::adddressof(b))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap). This won't need a using-declaration.

See also: [`std::is_swappable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_swappable).

This is separate from the C++20 concept [`swappable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/swappable), which uses [`std::ranges::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/ranges/swap), though that might be what you want to use.